# Setting string intentions to filepath

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I love intelliLang in jetbrains, but one thing I would like to know is what option do I choose to make it see my intention as a file path.

For example, you can change intention from `css` and `scss` and the like. How do you give it the intention that, *this is a file path*?

Comment: All intentions are hard coded, i.e. can only be invoked in specific places (e.g. you cannot invoke "test regex" intention on string that looks like regex -- you have to inject RegEx language to have it). The IDE must know (somehow) about such places (e.g. that "path complete" intention should be available here) -- currently you cannot give such hint via special comment or something -- it's all must be done from inside (plugin code).

Comment: @LazyOne: Well you can via intelliLang. I tried it in phpstorm, it just does not have something for a filepath.

Comment: *"Well you can via intelliLang"* -- please explain/show example -- I do not get this.

Comment: @LazyOne: Well if you have phpstorm, just make an empty string in something like java-script. Then Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then you have an option to inject language. That is what I meant.

Comment: Yes, it's called **Language Injection** and I have mentioned that in my first comment. In any case: this way you are injecting language, which **does know** what intentions and where it can apply; but you cannot apply random intention to a **random** string (via some sort of special comment or whatever, unfortunately).

Comment: My suggestion: file a Feature Request ticket to the Issue Tracker with the places where such "file chooser" intention should be applied. If it's not framework (your code only) specific, then I would definitely vote for it myself. If it's about "I want to have such intention in any random place I want" -- feel free to submit such ticket as well .. but I do not think they will have it as a priority at all.